# What does asterisk mean in the logical expression of an "IF" function?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

For example, in this formula, what the asterisk does:

```
=IF ((A2: E <> "") * (A2: E <> "-"); "X"; "Y")
```

It would be something similar to `= IF (AND (`... ?

Where can I study this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means `AND` and the reason is that `ARRAYFORMULA` does not support `AND` nor `OR` so

- `AND` is `*`
- `OR` is `+`

it's just a 0/1 logic

```
TRUE  * TRUE  = TRUE       as:     1 * 1 = 1
TRUE  * FALSE = FALSE      as:     1 * 0 = 0
FALSE * TRUE  = FALSE      as:     0 * 1 = 0
FALSE * FALSE = FALSE      as:     0 * 0 = 0
```